# Difference between SQLAlchemy `Float`, `FLOAT`, `REAL`

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has three main types for floating point numbers, `Float`, `FLOAT`, and `REAL`.  What is the semantic difference between these?  Is there anything that consistently maps to 32 and 64 bit floating point numbers across dialects?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.FLOAT, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.REAL

Comment: @false yes, but I didn't come away with a clear answer to my question.  Did I miss something?

Comment: `REAL` consistently maps to 32 bits. Apart from that… you might have to use dialect-specific `DOUBLE`s, or set precision (which is usually appropriate, but probably doesn’t guarantee any number of bits).

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

`Float` is a SQLAlchemy object type that encompasses several floats as defined in SQL, such as `FLOAT` or `REAL`.

The difference between `FLOAT` or `REAL` in the SQL world is that `FLOAT` stores single-precision *and* double-precision floating-point numbers, whereas `REAL` stores *just* single-precision floating-point numbers.

---

### Details

From [the SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html?highlight=float#sqlalchemy.types.Float) at the time of writing:

> [`Float` is a] type representing floating point types, such as `FLOAT` or `REAL`.

From [here](https://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-099.html):

> **`FLOAT[(n)]`**
>
> `FLOAT` data type is used to store single-precision and double-precision
> floating-point numbers.
>
> A single-precision floating-point number is a 32-bit approximation of
> a real number. The number can be zero or can range from -3.402E+38 to
> -1.175E-37, or from 1.175E-37 to 3.402E+38. The range of n is 1 to 24. IBM DB2 internally represents the single-precision `FLOAT` data type as
> the `REAL` data type.
>
> A double-precision floating-point number is a 64-bit approximation of
> a real number. The number can be zero or can range from -1.79769E+308
> to -2.225E-307, or from 2.225E-307 to 1.79769E+308. The range of n is
> 25 to 53. IBM DB2 internally represents the double-precision `FLOAT` data
> type as the `DOUBLE [PRECISION]` data type.
>
> If n is not specified the default value is 53.
>
> **`REAL`**
>
> A single-precision floating-point number.